# How to increase width of nz-Drawer for Component/Templet? link for reference is http://ng-zorro.cn/components/drawer/en

Tags: angular7

how to increase nz-drawer component width. It is fixed with default size and I cannot find any internal class name to increase the width.

Link for reference :- http://ng-zorro.cn/components/drawer/en

Answer (score 1):

i opened the document and in api section i saw `[nzWidth]` have you tried this ?
it works like this 
`<whatEverTheTagIs [nzWidth]="300" > </whatEverTheTagIs>`
300 number is just example you can put whatever you want

or what abut this one `[nzWrapClassName]`
with this you can add a class to container of your dialog

Comment: Thank you, it rectified the problem, But I used it with component drawer inside .ts file because I am using component drawer.

Answer (score 0):

This is where I used **nzWidth:900px** to increase the **component drawer**.
It works fine.

`const drawerRef = this.drawerService.create<NzDrawerCustomComponent, { value: string }, string>({
      nzTitle: 'Component',
      nzContent: NzDrawerCustomComponent,
      nzWidth:'900px',
      nzContentParams: {
        value: this.value
      }
    });`